# On element click modal pops up for the first time, but not for the second time

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a table in which data is filled dynamically using Ajax.

I add an edit button so that I can edit data. On clicking edit button a modal would appear and on submit, data would be updated. The click works fine for the first time. And the modal gets pop up and gets vanished. But when I click on the edit icon on the second time. Nothing happens.

I tried searching and placing my function under $(function() {} but that didn't worked.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="TasksTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Task #</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>



function showTables() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url() ?>TaskController/showTasks',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {

                var html = '';
                var i;

                if (data.length == 0) {
                    $('#TaskCount').html('<p class="text-warning text- 
center">Hooray! No tasks Left. Consider Taking a break OR Adding new 
Tasks</p>');
                }
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].task_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].task_date + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + data[i].task_status + '</td>' +
                        '<td><div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d- 
inline pr-3"><input type="checkbox" name="chkboxes" class="custom-control- 
input" data="' + data[i].task_id + '" id="customCheck' + data[i].task_id + 
'"><label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck' + data[i].task_id 
+ '"></label></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img 
class="editicon" data="' + data[i].task_id + '" src="<?php echo base_url() 
?>images/edit.png" width="17px;" style="vertical-align: unset;"></td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                }

                $('#tableBody').html(html);
            },

            error: function() {
                console.log("Error Fetching Data");
            }
        });
    }



$(function() {
        showTables();

        // $('#tableBody').on('click','.editicon', function() {
            $('.editicon').on('click', function() {
            console.log('click');
            // Display Form to update form and update data
            var taskId = $(this).attr('data');
            console.log(taskId);

            $('#editTaskModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url()? 
>TaskController/fetchTaskByID',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    taskId: taskId
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#editTaskID').val(taskId);
                    $('#editTaskName').val(data[0].task_name);
                    $('#editTaskDate').val(data[0].task_date);
                },

                error: function() {
                    console.log('Can\'t update status');
                }
            });

        });
    });

    $('#editTaskForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var taskID = $('#editTaskID').val();
        var taskName = $('#editTaskName').val();
        var taskDate = $('#editTaskDate').val();


        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url() ?>TaskController/UpdateTask',
            method: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#editTaskModal').modal('hide');
                $('#editTaskForm')[0].reset();
                showTables();
            },

            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to fully replicate your issue. Here is a basic example that does add data dynamically and I can see that click event is fired more than once when clicked more than once.

```js
$(function() {
  var siteUrl = "<?php echo site_url() ?>";
  var exData = {
    task_id: 100,
    task_name: "Example Task",
    task_date: "01/01/1970",
    task_status: "Completed"
  }

  function addTask(tObj, ind, rData) {
    var newRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(tObj);
    $("<td>").html(ind).appendTo(newRow);
    $("<td>").html(rData.task_name).appendTo(newRow);
    $("<td>").html(rData.task_date).appendTo(newRow);
    $("<td>").html(rData.task_status).appendTo(newRow);
    var task = $("<td>").appendTo(newRow);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "custom-control custom-checkbox d-inline pr-3"
    }).appendTo(task);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "chkboxes" + rData.task_id,
      id: "customCheck" + rData.task_id
    }).appendTo($("div", task));
    $("<label>", {
      class: "custom-control-label",
      for: "customCheck" + rData.task_id
    }).appendTo($("div", task));
    $("<img>", {
      class: "editicon",
      src: siteUrl + "images/edit.png",
    }).data("task-id", rData.task_id).css({
      width: "17px",
      "vertical-align": "unset"
    }).appendTo(task);
    return newRow;
  }

  function showTables() {
    $.ajax({
      url: siteUrl + 'TaskController/showTasks',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var html = '';
        var table = $("#tableBody");
        if (data.length == 0) {
          $('#TaskCount').html('<p class="text-warning text-center">Hooray! No tasks Left. Consider Taking a break OR Adding new Tasks </p>');
        } else {
          $.each(data, function(i, d) {
            addTask(table, i + 1, d);
          });
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Error Fetching Data");
      }
    });
  }

  addTask($("#tableBody"), 0, exData);
  showTables();

  $('.editicon').on('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
    // Display Form to update form and update data
    var taskId = $(this).data("task-id");
    console.log(taskId);
    $('#editTaskModal').modal('show');
    $.ajax({
      url: siteUrl + 'TaskController/fetchTaskByID',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        taskId: taskId
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#editTaskID').val(taskId);
        $('#editTaskName').val(data[0].task_name);
        $('#editTaskDate').val(data[0].task_date);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('Can\'t update status');
      }
    });
  });

  $('#editTaskForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var taskID = $('#editTaskID').val();
    var taskName = $('#editTaskName').val();
    var taskDate = $('#editTaskDate').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: siteUrl + 'TaskController/UpdateTask',
      method: 'POST',
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#editTaskModal').modal('hide');
        $('#editTaskForm')[0].reset();
        showTables();
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Error');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.d-inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-checkbox {
  margin-right: 7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="TasksTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Task #</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I did a lot of minor cleanup to ensure the HTML Syntax was correct. Since I was unsure about the opening and closing tags, I switched the creation to jQuery. I also moved it to it's own function so it's a bit easier to handle.

I am guessing that the issue is related to your Modal and how it's "closed" or removed. For example, if not removed properly, the click event might be prevented.

Comment: I replicated your code on the localhost. But, it shows a blank table with no data in it. https://imgur.com/a/67TsK3Y

Comment: Nothing. No error or warning. I check the source tab. Jquery is loading fine.

Comment: @Ankit maybe pastebin your resulting Source Code. Also check the Networking section since you're making an AJAX call to see what the result is if it's even going out.

Comment: Hi. I figured out the solution for it.